# How to make ssd my c: file?

Tags: ssd

i got new pc
and i have 256GB Samsung 830 SSD
and 2 TB HDD
OS : Windows 7 Professional 64 bit
after doing the hardware build, how to make the c: file my ssd and d: my hdd?
can i do it with the bios or ?

Comment: Do you just want do change drive letters or move the entire OS to your new drive?

Comment: Are you trying to move your Windows installation onto your SSD? If so, did your SSD come with software or directions?

Answer (score 1):

Install the SSD in the computer and install Windows. When it's done installing put your HDD in there and reboot. Go into my computer > right click 2TB drive and select format (You said it was new). It will either ask you to assign a drive letter or automatically assign D:/ to it. That's it.

Answer (score 1):

If i am understanding correctly you wish to make your SSD the primary Hard Drive with Windows Installed and running off it.

If this is the case there is a simple enough way to do this without having to reinstall windows and programs as long as the 2TB drive does not have more than 256GB of data on it you can use MiniTool Partition Wizard Home Edition software is free download here http://download.cnet.com/MiniTool-Partition-Wizard-Home-Edition/3000-2094_4-10962200.html

Clone 2TB to the SSD change the boot drive in the bios to the SSD

Mission accomplished, format the 2TB after